# I have a TemplateDoesNotExist error. I can update my models but not delete them?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm making my first Django site that has one app so far named clients and i keep my templates in project_name/clients/templates/clients.

Like the title says i'm able to update an instance of my model Client using UpdateView in my views file and I thought I would be able to delete an instance in the same way using DeleteView but I get the error stated previously. Any help would be appreciated. I've seen other similar posts but nothing that helped me solve this problem

Here's my url file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'clients'

url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

# /clients/11/... could be any number
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

# /clients/viewed/
url(r'^viewed/', views.viewed, name='viewed'),

# /clients/add/
url(r'^add/$', views.ClientCreate.as_view(), name='client-add'),

# /clients/3/update/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update$', views.ClientUpdate.as_view(), name='client-update'),

# /clients/8/delete/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.ClientDelete.as_view(), name='client-delete'),

]
```

Here's the relevant classes in my views.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Client


class ClientUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Client
    fields = ['name', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 
'history_of_head_trauma', 'profession', 'is_athlete', 'email']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clients:index')


class ClientDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Client
    success_url = reverse_lazy('clients:index')
```

Here's the div in my index.html that holds both buttons for updating and deleting:

```
 <div class="panel-footer">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
          <span class="pull-right">
                <a href="{% url 'clients:client-update' pk=client.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                 <a href="{% url 'clients:client-delete' pk=client.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>

            </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: In which directory your index.html is?

Comment: include IndexView class in your question

Comment: Show the full `TemplateDoesNotExist` error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason when using UpdateView, your button in html can be just a simple link with the href pointing to the correct url which in my case pointed to ClientUpdate in my views file ...

But for DeleteView the html has to be in a `<form>`. This was the only code i had to change to make this work. I basically put the form in place of the 
    `<a href="{% url 'clients:client-delete' pk=client.id %}"....>`

```
<div class="panel-footer">
  <a type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
    <span class="pull-right">
      <a href="{% url 'clients:client-update' pk=client.id %}" type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
      <form action="{% url 'clients:client-delete' pk=client.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="{{ client.id }}"/>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-small">
                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                </button>
        </form>
     </span>
```

Comment: Even if you change your index to submit a post request, it would be a good idea to add the missing template. Otherwise you'll get errors when users/bots navigate to the delete URL directly.

Comment: Note that the hidden input `client_id` is not required -- you already have the `client_id` in the form's `action`.

Comment: Given that DeleteView requires a form to confirm deletion, is it "better" not to use inherit from DeleteView if I don't want a delete confirmation form?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `DeleteView` shows a confirmation page for get requests, and deletes the object for post requests. You need to create a template `clients/client_confirm_delete.html` (or set `template_name` on the view) to handle GET requests. There is an example template [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview):

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete "{{ object }}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

Your other option is to add a form to your index page, so that users submit a post request to the delete page. Note that this means that the object will be deleted immediately without confirmation. Even if you do this, it might be a good idea to add a template for GET requests, otherwise you could get errors when users/bots navigate directly to your delete url.

Answer (score 0):

u need to create a dedicated HTML page inside the CBV to execute the delete operation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).